# NSMutableArray cast to swift Array of custom type

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

I'd like to figure out how to specify or cast an NSMutableArray to a swift Array of a custom type. I currently have 2 files:

1. First file requires an NSMutableArray for its functionality (passed by reference, ability to remove particular objects with indices I don't know)
2. Second file uses a Swift array (better memory / throwaway array), with a custom type, which I declare using

`let newArray: [CustomType]!`

I need to pass the NSMutableArray in as a parameter to a function in the second file, which requires a [CustomType]. When simply calling it:

`let newVC = UIViewController(array: mutableArray)`

it keeps telling me `'CustomType' is not identical to 'AnyObject'`. I've tried calling the function using `mutableArray as [CustomType]`, which does not work either. How can I make the swift Array function accept my NSMutableArray?

Comment: Did you refer this http://dev.eltima.com/post/96538497489/convert-nsmutablearray-to-swift-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was this:

let newVC = UIViewController(array: mutableArray as AnyObject as [CustomType])

Comment: Cool, that is very compact syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

`var swiftArray = NSArray(array:mutableArray) as Array<CustomType>`

`swiftArray` is then a Swift array of objects of CustomType. You can pass the array and iterate over it as you would expect.

Comment: Note this only works if your NSMutableArray contains CustomType objects.